# Keras-tuner doesn't use the whole training dataset, how can one adjust it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hyperparameters, keras-tuner

I'm currently stuck in my masterthesis. I'm trying to do a Bayesian Optimization for the hyperparameter tuning with the Keras-Tuner. I have a training dateset containing 4131 samples, but keras-tuner only uses 130 datapoints for the tuning. I'd like to use all the data or at least almost.

this the code I use:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVrmK.png)

this is what I don't get:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gszya.png)

google, stackoverflow and chatgpt couldn't help me til now, couldn't find a similar problem